# c# system to display country names without receiving country codes on the phone

Tags: c#

how can we identify a phone number without a country code ? 
 DataTable cnc = CNC();
            DataTable countrySwitch = CS();

```
        DataRow[] rows;
        //string clngnum = dReader["DPC"].ToString();
        foreach (DataRow dr in Mdt.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                string ID = dr["ID"].ToString();
                //dr["DestinationCountry"] = CountrySwitch(dr["DPC"].ToString());

                string Callingnum = dr["CallingNumber"].ToString();
                string CalledNum = dr["CalledNumber"].ToString();

                if (Callingnum != "" && CalledNum != "" && Callingnum != "0" && Callingnum != "00" && Callingnum != "000")
                {

                    while (Callingnum.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
                        Callingnum = Callingnum.Remove(0, 1);
```

Comment: this is just sample incomplete code if the country code is given but what if if the country code is missing ??

Comment: Hi dave, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you make the question clearer, please?  Do you mean that you want to determine whether a number has a country code or not?  What is your available set of country codes (mobile, fixed...?) Is there a more relevant SO tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't. There are several phone number length specifications around the world, and lack of country code can make its resolution dubious.

For example, US follows the [North American Numbering Plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan), whose format is as follows:

+1 (NPA) NXX-xxxx

Where:

- **1** - US international Country Calling code
- **NPA** - Numbering Plan Area Code
- **NXX** - Central Office (exchange) code
- **xxxx** - Subscriber Number

Several countries follow the same pattern, and using the same codes for different specifications - for example, the NPA-equivalent field in Brazilian numbering plan relates to state/city, while the NXX-equivalent may have anything between 3 and 5(!) numbers. So, let's assume this valid Brazilian number:

```
(15) 93935-5555
```

and this US number (This NPA doesn't exist, just fyi):

```
[+1]-(593) 935-5555
```

So, not only you can't because patterns overlap, but also if you're not sure you have the full number it may resolve to the wrong country.

Comment: Thank you but to make my question clear i'm doing in some project that  receives a calling and called numbers and conversations too then we want to add calling number originating country and the destination country by just simply comparing the country code of the calling and called party with the database that has a country code and country name but the problem comes with a calling number with no country code so how can we define the country name of the calling party .... ???